# For a rear wheel driven motorcycle, why is the reaction force acted on the rear wheel greater than that on the front wheel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, everyday-life, free-body-diagram

Is it because there’s a greater frictional force on the rear wheel as it is responsible for the acceleration of the motorcycle?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not sufficiently specific. The relationship between the reaction force on each wheel depends upon many factors, so you ought to specify the circumstances you have in mind. The weight distribution is one- so that depends upon the design of the bike, whether it has a pillion passenger, etc. The state of acceleration is another- under heavy acceleration, the torque imposed on the rear wheel produces a reaction which transfers weight from the front to the rear (you will have seen motorcycles perform 'wheelies' in extreme cases, where there is no weight at all on the front wheel). Under heavy braking with the front brake, weight will be transferred to the front wheel, so the reaction force might be greater at the front.

The frictional component of the reaction force will also vary with the factors I have listed, as well as others, such as tyre design and the roughness of the road surface. It will also vary with applied torque under acceleration, causing it to be greater at the rear than at the front.